# Nhibernate setFirstResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm having an issue with Nhibernate version 3.3.3 when trying to use setFirstResult.

```
IQuery q = session.CreateQuery("Select a from SelectionAssignment a ") 
                .SetFirstResult(1)
                .SetMaxResults(10);

var assignments = q.List<SelectionAssignment>();
```

The above spits out SQL like this:

```
SELECT TOP (10) asId30_
, asHostId30_
, asDescript3_30_
, asIsChase30_
, asPosition30_
, asGoalTime30_
, asRoute30_
, asActiveta8_30_
, asPassAssi9_30_
, asSummary10_30_
, asOverrid11_30_
, asDeliver12_30_
, asDirectLoad30_
, asAllowDe14_30_
, asVehicle15_30_
, asCustomerId30_
, asTotalWe17_30_
, asTotalItems30_
, asSingleSKU30_
, asSingleB20_30_
, asCreated21_30_
, asStartDate30_
, asEndDate30_
, asPriority30_
, asIsDeleted30_
, asDeleted26_30_
, asDeleted27_30_ FROM 
(
select selectiona0_.Id as Id30_
, selectiona0_.HostId as HostId30_
, selectiona0_.Description as Descript3_30_
, selectiona0_.IsChase as IsChase30_
, selectiona0_.Position as Position30_
, selectiona0_.GoalTime as GoalTime30_
, selectiona0_.Route as Route30_
, selectiona0_.ActivetargetContainer as Activeta8_30_
, selectiona0_.PassAssignment as PassAssi9_30_
, selectiona0_.SummaryPromptType as Summary10_30_
, selectiona0_.OverridePrompt as Overrid11_30_
, selectiona0_.DeliveryLocationId as Deliver12_30_
, selectiona0_.DirectLoad as DirectLoad30_
, selectiona0_.AllowDeliverLocationOverride as AllowDe14_30_
, selectiona0_.VehicleLicense as Vehicle15_30_
, selectiona0_.CustomerId as CustomerId30_
, selectiona0_.TotalWeight as TotalWe17_30_
, selectiona0_.TotalItems as TotalItems30_
, selectiona0_.SingleSKU as SingleSKU30_
, selectiona0_.SingleBatch as SingleB20_30_
, selectiona0_.CreatedDate as Created21_30_
, selectiona0_.StartDate as StartDate30_
, selectiona0_.EndDate as EndDate30_
, selectiona0_.Priority as Priority30_
, selectiona0_.IsDeleted as IsDeleted30_
, selectiona0_.DeletedDate as Deleted26_30_
, selectiona0_.DeletedUser as Deleted27_30_
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_sort_row 
from SelectionAssignment selectiona0_ where ( selectiona0_.IsDeleted=0)
) as query
 WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > 0 
 ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

Whereas if I set the parameter to be .SetFirstResult(0) it works fine.

Can anyone tell me why? Or how I could go about fixing this?

Edit: Apologies, I'm getting an error message of Invalid column name 'asId30' 'asHostId30' etc. The column name is Id, HostId etc.

Comment: I guess this may be a stupid comment, but could you point where the problem is ?

Comment: Sorry edited to explain

Comment: Might be a dialect problem, but, first thing to add is an ORDER BY in your select statement. First and Max are meaningless without it.

Comment: I added in an order by and it made no difference. I've tried it using both the 2008 and 2012 dialects. Both of them produce the incorrect query.

Comment: What happens if you switch the querying model with : var assignments = session.Query<SelectionAssignment>().OrderBy(a => a.Id).Skip(1).Take(10).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. It seemed to be the column name "SelectionAssignment" was causing an issue because NHibernate uses it's own alias on the produced SQL which takes 10 characters and adds a digit. However the 10th and 11th character in my column name are "AS". This seemed to cause a conflict with the query when it tried to put its own AS in there.

Once I changed the column name to be something different "PickingAssignment" the issue was fixed.

I hope I've explained clearly enough and that it can help others with the same issue. Thanks to jbl for trying to help.